# Lucene.NET C# - Searching "Exact Terms" in the same order from a sentence

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.Net 3.0.3
I am trying to index and search a "exact phrase" in the same order of the words from a sentence.

Example:
I have these four sentences which has been indexed.

- Support Request for Unit Testing From Web Site
- Request for Support - Having an issues
- Request for a new Keyboard
- Support DB enhancements

I want to search exactly for "**Support Request**". Currently it returns all, as both the words are present in all four sentences in different order. 
But i want the very first sentence alone to be returned

How to achieve this?
Lucene.NET 3.0.3
C#, .NET 4.0, Windows Forms

Comment: Use a `PhraseQuery` (or use double quotes in the query parser). You also need to index positions. You'll have to show *how* you construct your query if you want any further help.

Comment: Hi, This is the Query that is being executed `+TextLine:support +TextLine:request`  and the field is added to the index like this ` d.Add(new Field("TextLine", CheckIfNull(strTxtLine), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));` Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, it's bad. It should be `TextLine:"support request"` - show the code that generated this query.

Comment: How to index a field with positions?

Comment: It should have positions by default, your field looks OK. Your query is wrong though.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, It worked. I have to use the query *TextLine:"support request"* like this as you said.